# Reorder DOM elements

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, css-float, transpose

I have CSS floated elements with predefined width and I want them to transpose from rows to columns. Actually reordering them to look as if they were ordered by columns instead of rows as is usual with floated elements...

So the easiest way to put elements in columns is to use `float: left;` on them. The problem is that we get ordering from **left to right & top to bottom** instead of **top to bottom & left to right** (as we can see in phone books for instance that use columns and data flows in columns not rows). The latter is much easily searchable when elements are ordered alphabetically because it's easier to follow columns than rows.

Anyway.

I know I could use CSS3 columns which list elements in the top-bottom-left-right order, but the problem is that IE **still** doesn't support them even in IE9.

### What I actually need

What I need is a jQuery plugin that determines the number of floated elements per row and reorder them, so that they appear in the top-bottom-left-right order.

This can only work of course when floated elements have a predefined fixed width. If they don't they don't appear being columns anyway.

#### Question

Is there a plugin for this functionality so I don't have to write my own? Because otherwise I will obviously have to.

> **Note for future reference**: I've written such jQuery plugin which can be found [here](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/07/use-css-floats-to-flow-data-in-columns.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, because I literally JUST coded something like this for a project. I had a UL with a list of items in alphabetical order, but the ordering went from left to right instead of top/down per column.

The following script reorders the LIs accordingly:

```
var $lists = $('ul.list');
var columnCount = 3;

// reorder the ul so that the columns are left to right and still alphabetized
$lists.each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    var $newList = $('<ul class="list" />');
    var $lis = $ul.children('li');
    var itemCount = $lis.size();
    var leftovers = itemCount % columnCount;
    var itemsPerColumn = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
      itemsPerColumn[i] = Math.floor(itemCount / columnCount) + (i < leftovers ? 1 : 0);
    }

    var offsetIndex = 0;
    var rowIndex = 0;

    $lis.each(function(i){
      var $li = $(this);
      var columnIndex = i % columnCount;
      $lis.eq(offsetIndex).clone().appendTo($newList)
      offsetIndex += itemsPerColumn[columnIndex];

      if (offsetIndex >= itemCount) offsetIndex = ++rowIndex;
    });

    $ul.replaceWith($newList);
});
```

Comment: Thanks alex. With a bit of refactoring this is actually what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there is a plugin but here you go (accompanied fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58akv/1/):

jQuery:

```
    // This is me being lazy and not wanting to copy/paste box 50 times
    var box = $('div.box');
    for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
        box.clone().text(i).appendTo(box.parent());
    }
    // Now that we have all elements
    var i = 0;
    // Specify how many you'd like per row, if you want to
    var rowsPerColumn = 0;
    var cols = 0;
    $('.box').each(function() {
        // remove float
        $(this).css("float", "none");

        if ($(this).parent('.col').length == 0) {
            // if rowsPerColumn is 0 or undefined, figure it out ourselves
            if (rowsPerColumn == 0 || !rowsPerColumn) {
                // calculate how many fit into given width
                var totalColumns = Math.floor($("#wrapper")[0].clientWidth / $(this).outerWidth(true));
                // calculate how many boxes go into each column
                rowsPerColumn = Math.ceil($('.box', '#wrapper').length / totalColumns);
            }
            // wrap this and next in col
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var els = $(this).add($(this).siblings('.box').slice(0, rowsPerColumn-1));
            parent.append($('<div></div>').addClass('col').append(els).attr('id', 'col'+ (++cols).toString()))
        }
    });
```

CSS (for example purposes):

```
.box {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
}

.col { float: left; }
```

HTML (for example purposes):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this is not what I want exactly, because you start with unfloated elements and then calculate how many go into certain width and then wrap each column and float wrapper. Anyway. I have to start with already floated elements and determine how many are there in a row and then reorder existing elements. I suppose it will be a more simple algorithm than yours. I suppose...

Comment: @Robert Aside from the point you made about starting with a float (which is trivial and so I've updated the fiddle), the logic/algorithm gives you the same number of rows as there would be if you didn't re-arrange them. When you say "determine how many there are in a row" (in terms of when they're simply floated) and I say "determine the number of columns", we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: @Robert I've added more descriptive comments to the javascript hoping that you'll be able to understand what I mean.

Comment: I understood you code before as well. Thanks anyway. I just personally think that it's better to determine correct number of columns by examining current situation than the way you've calculated it (which is wrong anyway, since you're using `$("#wrapper").outerWidth()` which is wrong because available wrapper space is only inner space without padding. But even if you used `innerWidth` it also adds in padding. But. They both have a problem when we have a scrollbar. Hence my decision to rather determine number of columns based on existing floated situation.

Comment: @Robert argh it's hard to manage jsfiddles, SO answers, and the local version I have of this. I made that fix in my local version. As for padding, it's a non-issue, just set padding to 0 on the wrapper. As for the scroll bar, you can use `$('#wrapper')[0].clientWidth`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth

Comment: Ok. maybe I've described my problem incorrectly. I have a container which may have padding, birder and margin set to whatever and I can't change that just like *it's a non-issue, just set padding to 0*. That's just can't be done. And my elements are already loaded as floated. **And** it has to be universal without specifying some CSS classes as you did. And I can't break existing document structure (hence no wrapping is allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Here's plugin; tried it, works great!
https://github.com/litera/jquery-transpose

Comment: I don't know whether you've clicked on the link in the question but I've added a link up there to [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/07/use-css-floats-to-flow-data-in-columns.html) that describes this plugin you linked. I've written this plugin as a result to this very question... Asked by me.

Comment: BTW: I'm very glad to hear it works great for you. It works great for me as well. :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize it was you that asked the questions :-) I had one issue and it was using it against a list inside a display:none element (that is shown later). I realize that there's no height so it can't make calculations; so a great feature would be to specify the number of columns and override the automated math.